# why there is no response when using android retrofit although i can see the request?

Tags: android, retrofit

i am using android retrofit to send a post request to my laravel server. What i am facing is that i can get the request body on the server side, but there is no response (onResponse method does not run). 
API interface:

```
package com.example.asus.retrofit;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface Api {
    String BASE_URL="http://405d6d4f.ngrok.io/";
    @POST("execute")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<ServerJsonObject> sendData(@Field("name") String name);

}
```

my ServerJsonObject class:

```
public class ServerJsonObject {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        Call<ServerJsonObject> call = api.sendData("Mathew");

       call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerJsonObject>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<ServerJsonObject> call, Response<ServerJsonObject> response) {
               ServerJsonObject x = response.body(); // it doesn't enter here when debugging
               Log.d("data",Integer.toString(x.getAge()));
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<ServerJsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

           }
       });
    }
}
```

response that my server returns:

> {"name":"Mathew","age":22}

I can see request body on server side, it's as the following:

> name=Mathew

Comment: check if it calling OnFailure. Keep the log and check

Comment: can you show ServerJsonObject.class code?

Comment: Put one log inside onFailure() and show us the response

Comment: `t.printStackTrace();`

Comment: If it does not called onResponse() then it  calls onFailure(). Put log inside onFailure() to make sure.